# Calling a javascript function from Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

**It's a simple context: 
I have a simple javascript file called myJs.js in a Amazon S3 bucket, like this:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
alert("Help my!!");
}
</script>
```

**I just want to call it, from a django html template hosted in Heroku, like this:**

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>Calling a S3's js from Heroku </title>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/js.myBucket/myJs.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
         <input type="button" name="test" value="Click me" onclick="myFunction()">
    </body>
</html>
```

**It doesn't work. By the way: it is not a MIME trouble.**

Comment: Looks fine. Any errors in the browser console? How about a http://jsfiddle.net that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file shouldn’t contain the `<script>` tags; it’s JavaScript, not HTML. (Check your browser’s console — it will tell you where the syntax error is.)